# Getting a Textbox to show up when a radio option is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get this function to show/hide the text box element. So far I have had little luck. Can anyone show me how to show and hide the element by setting its style visible or not pending on what radio option you have selected?
Here is what I have so far.

Scripts

```
            function hide(id)
            {
                document.getElementById(id).style.visibility='hidden';
            }

            function show(id)
            {
                document.getElementById(id).style.visibility='visible'; 
            }
```

html

```
            <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-theme="c" id="quests'+id+'">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <label>Question?</label>

            <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="'+QuestionID+'_1" value="1" onClick="show("comment_'+QuestionID+'")"/>
            <label for="'+QuestionID+'_1">Yes</label>

            <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="'+QuestionID+'_0" value="0" onclick="hide("comment_'+QuestionID+'")"/>
            <label for="'+QuestionID+'_0">No</label>
            </fieldset>

            //I am trying to make these visable if yes is selected
            <textarea cols="30" rows="8" name="textarea" style="width:80%; visibility:hidden;" id="comment_'+QuestionID+'"></textarea>
            <br />
            </div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to fix your IDs first. '+QuestionID+'_1 doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onSelect` doesn't make any sense on a radio button... it is used for "selecting" text in an input field.  Use `onClick` instead. However, if you use `onClick`, you will need to check if the radio button is actually selected or not, so this would complicate your JS portion.

Since you tagged the question as "jQuery", here is what I would do:

HTML:

```
<div class="radioToggle" data-role="fieldcontain" data-theme="c" id="quests'+id+'">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <label>Question?</label>

        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="'+QuestionID+'_1" value="1" />
        <label for="'+QuestionID+'_1">Yes</label>

        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="'+QuestionID+'_0" value="0" />
        <label for="'+QuestionID+'_0">No</label>
    </fieldset>

    //I am trying to make these visable if yes is selected
    <textarea cols="30" rows="8" name="textarea" style="width:80%; visibility:hidden;" id="comment_'+QuestionID+'"></textarea>
    <br />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.radioToggle').on('click', 'input:radio', function(){
    var parent = $(this).closest('.radioToggle'),
        textbox = parent.find('textbox');
    if ($(this).attr('id') == '1') {
        textbox.show();
    } else {
        textbox.hide();
    }
})
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that it was not working with onClick either, however I did change it back to onClick.

Comment: onClick will fire not just when the radio button is clicked, but the text next to it as well. You probably want onChange.

Comment: Sure, but even with onChange, it will still have to check if the radiobox is selected or not. So not much is gained.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to accomplish something with generated code (probably php). Here's the gist of what you need to do:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" data-theme="c" id="quests'+id+'">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <label>Question?</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="1" data-id="123" />
        <label>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="0" data-id="123" />
        <label>No</label>
    </fieldset>
    <textarea cols="30" rows="8" name="textarea" style="width:80%; visibility:hidden;"></textarea>
    <br />
</div>
<div id="comment_123" style="display:none">here I am</div>
```

And the script:

```
$("input[type='radio']").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "1") {
        $('#comment_' + $(this).data("id")).show();
    } else {
        $('#comment_' + $(this).data("id")).hide();
    }
});
```

Here's a fiddle to illustrate the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/DgAHf/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type="radio"][name="radio1"]').on('change', function() {
    $('textarea[name="textarea"]').toggle($.trim(this.value)=='1');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5WF25/)